# How to select several dynamic span elements in a table

Tags: python, selenium

I am trying to pick the text located in tables. Dynamic means that there are sometimes one table and sometimes more than one tables. So my question is, how to pick the text from this tables.

This is what i tried:

```
from selenium import webdriver

# webdriver
browser = webdriver.Chrome("C:/Chrome/chromedriver.exe")
browser.get("http://homepage")

pick = browser.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[@id=\"xpath\"]/table[11]/tbody/tr/td/table[2]/tbody/tr/td[1]/span[2]")
pick.get_attribute("innerHTML")
```

and this is the xpath from each element:

```
//*[@id="xpath"]/table[11]/tbody/tr/td/table[2]/tbody/tr/td[1]/span[2]
//*[@id="xpath"]/table[11]/tbody/tr/td/table[3]/tbody/tr/td[1]/span[2]
//*[@id="xpath"]/table[11]/tbody/tr/td/table[4]/tbody/tr/td[1]/span[2]
```

and this is the html code:

```
<table style="width:700px; " border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="700px">
   <tbody>
      <tr>
         <td style="border:1px; border-style:solid; ">
            <table style="width:700px; " border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="700px">
               <tbody>
                  <tr>
                     <td style="border:1px; border-bottom-color:silver; border-bottom-style:solid; width:250px; " valign="top" width="250px"><span>&nbsp;</span><span style="font-size:10pt; font-weight:bold; "> </span></td>
                     <td style="border:1px; border-bottom-color:silver; border-bottom-style:solid; width:450px; " valign="middle" width="450px"><span style="font-size:10pt; "> </span><br></td>
                  </tr>
               </tbody>
            </table>
            <table style="width:700px; " border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="700px">
               <tbody>
                  <tr>
                     <td style="border:1px; border-bottom-color:silver; border-bottom-style:solid; width:250px; " valign="top" width="250px"><span>&nbsp;</span><span style="font-size:10pt; ">3</span></td>
                     <td style="border:1px; border-bottom-color:silver; border-bottom-style:solid; width:450px; " valign="middle" width="450px"><span style="font-size:10pt; ">Bleaching preparations and other substances for laundry use; cleaning, polishing, scouring and abrasive preparations; soaps; perfumery, essential oils, cosmetics, hair lotions; dentifrices (all the goods listed alphabetically in the Nice Classification, included in this class).</span><br></td>
                  </tr>
               </tbody>
            </table>
            <table style="width:700px; " border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="700px">
               <tbody>
                  <tr>
                     <td style="border:1px; border-bottom-color:silver; border-bottom-style:solid; width:250px; " valign="top" width="250px"><span>&nbsp;</span><span style="font-size:10pt; ">4</span></td>
                     <td style="border:1px; border-bottom-color:silver; border-bottom-style:solid; width:450px; " valign="middle" width="450px"><span style="font-size:10pt; ">Industrial oils and greases; lubricants; dust absorbing, wetting and binding compositions; fuels (including motor spirit) and illuminants; candles, wicks (all goods of this class included in the alphabetical list of Nice Classification).</span><br></td>
                  </tr>
               </tbody>
            </table>
            <table style="width:700px; " border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="700px">
               <tbody>
                  <tr>
                     <td style="border:1px; border-bottom-color:silver; border-bottom-style:solid; width:250px; " valign="top" width="250px"><span>&nbsp;</span><span style="font-size:10pt; ">5</span></td>
                     <td style="border:1px; border-bottom-color:silver; border-bottom-style:solid; width:450px; " valign="middle" width="450px"><span style="font-size:10pt; ">Pharmaceutical and veterinary preparations; sanitary preparations for medical purposes; dietetic foods and substances adapted for medical and veterinary use; food for babies; dietary supplements for humans and animals;plasters, materials for dressings; material for stopping teeth and dental wax; disinfectants; preparations for destroying vermin; fungicides, herbicides;(all goods of this class included in the alphabetical list of Nice Classification).</span><br></td>
                  </tr>
               </tbody>
            </table>
         </td>
      </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
```

thank you for any help!

Comment: you can try find_elements_by_tag_name("table") which will give you a list of all elements with table tag.And you can proceed with all the tables

Comment: list the steps you will do manually, and then try to think how you will automate.

Comment: What text are you trying to get? Be specific. Don't put code in comments, add them to the question so they can be properly formatted.